# Python regex: Line can't start with certain words, can only contain certain characters

Tags: python, regex

I am reading in lines from a file, and I want to remove lines that only contain letters, colon, parentheses, underscores, spaces and backslashes. This regex was working fine to find those lines...

```
[^A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\]
```

...as passed to re.search() as a raw string.

Now, I need to add to it that the lines cannot start with THEN or ELSE; otherwise they should not match and thus be exempted from being removed.

I tried just taking the ^ out of the brackets and adding a negative lookbehind before the bracketed expression, like so...

```
r'^(?!(ELSE|THEN))[A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\]'
```

...but now it just matches every line. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post what you tried, with the `^` and negative lookbehind?

Comment: I think it should be `^[^(THEN|ELSE)]\w+[^A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\]`, although I didn't test it.

Comment: Your regex is a single, negated character match... is that what you're using?

Comment: One resource I can highly recommend is this site. It'll allow you to put in the input you're searching in, then build a regex piece by piece: http://regexr.com/

Comment: @pkqxdd: you didn't well understand what are character classes: `[^(THEN|ELSE)]` is exactly the same than `[^()|EHLNST]`. Character classes are sets of characters, not sets of substrings, and regex special characters loose their special meaning inside them.

Comment: updated with what i had tried that wasn't doing what i'd hoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:.*[^A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\])|(?:THEN|ELSE)).*$
```

Broken down

```
^(?:                                        ).*$  #  Starts with
    (?:                      )|(?:         )      #  Either
       .*[^A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\]                     #  Anything that contains a non-alphanumeric character
                                  THEN|ELSE       #  THEN/ELSE
```

See the example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sLYuS8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just use an alternation:

```
^(?:THEN|ELSE|[A-Za-z0-9:()_\s\\]*$)
```

and remove the lines that **don't** match the pattern.